How do I avoid pixelation in an Imageview in an Android app?
I'm writing a music player app and want to show the album art with each song. Some of the album art looks just fine and other art is pixelated. There doesn't seem to be any pattern to the problem. I've checked the original files and they are not pixelated. For example, a .png picture of Eric Clapton is 3000 x 3000 and looks fine on my laptop, but when loaded into the Imageview in my app, it looks like this:
The images are not in the resources part of the Android Studio project - they are in folders mixed into the iTunes media folder, so the location of the file is defined in the artLocation field of my song database.
Here's how the Imageview is defined in the app:
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/albumArt"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="280dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/album_art"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/albumView" />

And here is how I add the image to the Imageview:
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(song.getArtLocation())) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(song.getArtLocation());
                //bitmap = Util.getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 2000, 2000);
                Bitmap newbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,800,800,false);
                albumArtView.setImageBitmap(newbitmap);
            } else {
                albumArtView.setImageResource(R.drawable.vinylrecord);
            }

I'm testing it on my Galaxy S9, which has Android 10. I also see the problem on my Lenova tablet that has Android 11. The target api in my project is 31.
I've tried setting the bitmap directly into the albumArtView, and also tried using two different methods of scaling the image (as you can see in the code). The commented out getResizedBitmap is some code I found online that looked promising, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the pixelation. I tried different resolutions in the Bitmap.createScaledBitmap and the getResizedBitmap methods, but it doesn't seem to make much difference.
It's not every album art file, just some of them. Some look fine. I would think the image in the app should look the same as the image viewed directly on my PC. Anyone have any ideas about what the problem is? If I should scale the image, what should the settings be?

Have you tried using an Image loading library (Picasso, Glide, Coil) to see if they fare any better?

Just tried Picasso, looks the same. I like the way the image fades in though!

Apologies - the example image on my phone was pixelated in the same way. I was looking at the image on my laptop in the itunes folder - which wasn't pixelated. Somehow it must have been corrupted when I synced my phone to my laptop. Picosso was a good find though - learned something!
